# D3.js - Rotate svg text around a point

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I rotate text with rectangle inside a Donut chart, I've tried by passing `text` selector in `d3.timer` but this changes `text` current state.

`text` will be always inside rectangle.

```
 var start = Date.now()
 d3.timer(function() {
   var angle = (Date.now() - start) * .3,
     rotate = function(d,i) {
        return "rotate(" + angle / 80 + ")";
    };
   wheel.selectAll("rect").attr("transform", rotate);
 });
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmdr72wc/45/)

Comment: You'll need a second selector for the text. e.g.,:  wheel.selectAll("text").attr("transform", rotate); Or you'll need to put everything inside a group.

Comment: @Incodeveritas I've tried this, but not working

Comment: The text selection definitely works.. the text just needs to be spaced out again.

Comment: @Incodeveritas you are saying something like this http://jsfiddle.net/kmdr72wc/49/ ? but it re-positioned text to center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the rotation to the `<g>` group which contains the text and rect. Note that you will have add the rotate transformation to the existing transformation matrix.

```
d3.timer(function() {       
    rect.each(function(){   
      var newTransform = this.getCTM().rotate(2), //Try with adding a fixed angle of rotation
      svgMatrix =  this.ownerSVGElement.createSVGTransformFromMatrix(newTransform);
      this.transform.baseVal.initialize(svgMatrix);
   });    
});
```

Here is the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmdr72wc/58/). Hope this helps.

Comment: this giving some hope, but not continuous rotation http://jsfiddle.net/kmdr72wc/54/